# Powershell get-acl from childitems that not equals foldername

Tags: powershell, directory, acl, subdirectory, get-childitem

At work we have a folder with lots of subfolders named like "MeyerS". (Lastname and the first letter of surname)

When I take a look at `Get-ChildItem $path | Get-Acl` the username equals the subfolder-name. But there is also a "SCHUELER\" in front of "MeyerS". This is what the output looks like a.e.:    `SCHUELER\MeyerS Allow  Write, ReadAndExecute, Synchronize`

Some subfolders don't have this kind of username. Now I want to output all these subfolders without this username- "combination".
With my first codesnippet I get all of them, but I really just want these specific ones.

I checked some similar questions, and found something. I modified it, but it shows **all** subfolders just without `SCHUELER\MeyerS`. I think I just need a small push to the right way.

The code so far:

```
 $path = "R:\HOME"
 $folders = Get-ChildItem $path | where {$_.psiscontainer}

 foreach ($folder in $folders){

      $domain = "domname"
      $aclname = "ACLname"
      $aclfullname ="$domain\$aclname"

      Get-Acl | select -ExpandProperty Access | where {$_.identityreference -notcontains $aclfullname}

      Write-Host $folder.FullName}
```

Short note: I tried a lot of variations with `-noteq` or `-notlike`.
What do I have to change?

If there is already an answer I really didn't know.
Sometimes it's really hard to enunciate yourself in another language. I hope you get my point.

Thanks.

Comment: Try: `Get-Acl | select -ExpandProperty Access | where {$_.identityreference -ne $aclfullname}  `

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried it a few minutes ago, but still all subfolders are listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$path = "R:\HOME"
$folders = Get-ChildItem $path | where {$_.psiscontainer}

foreach ($folder in $folders)
{

    $domain = "domname"
    $aclname = "ACLname"
    $aclfullname ="$domain\$aclname"
    $FoldersWithAclFullName = $null


    $FoldersWithAclFullName = Get-Acl -Path $Folder `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access `
    | Where-Object -Property IdentityReference -ne -Value $aclfullname

    if ( -not $FoldersWithAclFullName )
    {
        Write-Host $folder.FullName
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried your code. still all subfolders are listed.  I get this output: `Get-Acl : The path "MeyerS" can not be found, because it doesn't exist.`      I changed the path, but the error doesn't. Do you have some advice?

Comment: Try $FoldersWithAclFullName = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName